# Aurora PostgreSQL TEMP TABLE creation taking more CPU than expected?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-aurora

I'm running on an Aurora PostgreSQL on a `db.x2g.2xlarge` instance. Simply creating temporary table showed up as the third highest wait, which surprises me, as I expected it to be one of the lighest queries.

The query is called in a transaction:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE identifiers_to_resolve (  
  scheme_pk BIGINT,
  host_pk BIGINT,
  port INT NOT NULL,
  scheme_specific_part VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  index INTEGER NOT NULL
)  ON COMMIT DROP;
```

I want to use the temporary table as an in-transaction temporary store during a more complicated query.

The stats from performance insights:

- Load by waits (AAS): 0.42
- Calls/sec: 123.64
- Blk hits/sec: 48499.58
- Blk writes / sec: 16.32
- Avg latency ms / call: 3.24
- Blk hits/call 329.27
- Blk writes/call 0.13

All the other stats are 0.

Performance insights records the waits as nearly all "CPU". Screenshot attached.

[image: 39]

I think 123 calls per second is quite a low rate, and I'm surprised it's taxing the database this much, and touching this many blocks. From the use-cases I read around temporary tables, I expected them to have lower impact.

Is it typical that creating temporary tables causes this much CPU wait?

Comment: Related: https://dev.to/crushby/postgresql-and-temporary-tables-1ned ... yes temporary tables have some overload, it is amortized if you use them to store large result sets but if it's only a few rows it's a problem. Maybe you could use CTEs, curcors, or other temporary storage instead. You'll have to give more details on your queries.

Comment: My question wasn't about the reasons to use a temp table, more whether the simple `CREATE` should be that expensive, as it was a surprise. Thanks for that link, it was really useful in understanding what's going on.

Comment: Oops I meant overhead not overload. Anyway yes they're quite heavyweight, many updates in system catalogs (even more if you ANALYZE the temp table). Worth it if you want to store many thousands of rows or millions, but for just a few items (hundreds) to reuse between queries... if you can't use a CTE, it's probably faster to either do it on the client side and put the data back in the next query, or store it in a plpgsql variable and reuse it on the server (a plpgsql function can return the results of several queries).

Comment: Note if you use a connection pooler you can create the temp tables when the connection is opened and keep them for all subsequent uses of this connection. Simply create it with "ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS" so the table will be truncated after each use.  This skips table creation overhead, but TRUNCATE will do some file operations... so probably less overhead but not zero.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I have multiple concurrent transactions (each creating their own temp table which must be private to that transaction) on a connection pool. I wonder if the `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` would translate to this scenario? I guess if they all have their own transaction they won't see each others' data.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. If a temporary table is created when the connection is opened, it will stay alive for the duration of the connection (unless "on commit drop" is used). "on commit delete rows" makes most sense as it will truncate it after each use. But when several connections create temp tables with the same name, they're not the same table! They're distinct temp tables, one per connection, with the same name, but different disk files.

Comment: So the reason they won't see each other's rows isn't due to transaction vibility rules... but simply because they're different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing my comments into an answer:

```
begin; 
create temporary table foo2( id integer primary key) on commit drop; 
insert into foo select * from generate_series(1.100) n; 
select count(*) from foo; 
commit;

BEGIN          0.302 ms
CREATE TABLE   2.949 ms
INSERT 0 100   0.897 ms
count          0.377 ms
COMMIT         1.773 ms

Total          6.298 ms

create temporary table foo( id integer primary key) on commit delete rows; 

begin; 
insert into foo select * from generate_series(1.100) n; 
select count(*) from foo; 
commit;

BEGIN          0.276 ms
INSERT 0 100   1.191 ms
 count         0.510 ms
COMMIT         0.827 ms

Total          2.804 ms
```

Creating and destroying temp tables involves [file and system catalog operations](https://dev.to/crushby/postgresql-and-temporary-tables-1ned) which take time.

In the example above, this is visible at temp table creation, but also at commit, when it is deleted.

The more "permanent" temp table created with "on commit delete rows" avoids most of these operations, as it is simply truncated at the end of the transaction. Table creation and deletion are skipped, so it is much faster.

If you use a connection pooler you can create the temp tables when the connection is opened and keep them for all subsequent uses of this connection. Simply create them with "ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS" so the table will be truncated after each use.

If your pool uses [DISCARD ALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html) when getting an already-opened connection and passing it to a client, this drops temp tables too, so it should be changed. Unfortunately there is no way to discard everything except temp tables with one command, and it's not usually a good idea to have some state persist when connections are reused, so this needs a bit of thinking.

When several connections create temp tables with the same name, they're not the same table. They have the same name, but each temp table exists only in the system catalogs of the connection that opened it, and each has its own disk files.

So the reason they won't see each other's rows isn't due to transaction visibility rules... but simply because they're different tables.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really helpful.